# Psychopy: Call a conditions file from the outer loop's conditions file

Tags: nested-loops, psychopy

I am a bit new to `PsychoPy` and `Python` coding, so please excuse my question if it is basic. In my task, I have a number of files that dictate the position of stimuli. My outer loop has a variable, `ExcelList`, which has the previously mentioned file names listed under it. The inner loop, which dictates each trial, attempts to call these files at random by entering `$ExcelList` into the space asking for a conditions file. As I understand it, the command for `$ExcelList` should access the conditions file in the outer loop and pull one of the files containing stimuli positions for that trial. However, I am instead presented with the following error:

> File "/Users/bencline/Desktop/Psychexp/NegPriming2080_lastrun.py",
>   line 247, in module>
>       trialList=data.importConditions(ExcelList),   File "/Applications/PsychoPy2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/psychopy/data.py",
>   line 1366, in importConditions
>       raise ImportError('Conditions file not found: %s' %os.path.abspath(fileName)) ImportError: Conditions file not found:
>   /Users/bencline/Desktop/Psychexp/Trials_20_95.xlsx

It would appear that the inner loop is not finding the condition in the outer loop (or not reading the outer loop altogether). If I try instead writing `$eval(ExcelList)` I am presented with the following error:

> File "/Users/bencline/Desktop/Psychexp/NegPriming2080_lastrun.py",
>   line 247, in 
>       trialList=data.importConditions(eval(ExcelList)),   File "", line 1, in  NameError: name 'Trials_20_95' is not
>   defined

This seems more indicative of the underlying problem, but I'm still not sure how to proceed from here. Do you have any suggestions for why this is happening and how I could potentially fix it?

Thank you,

-Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategy is right. It reads your `ExcelList` in the outer loop but fails to find the filenames in `ExcelList` on your filesystem. In particular, in your first error message, it fails to find `/Users/bencline/Desktop/Psychexp/Trials_20_95.xlsx`. So check whether it actually exists. I strongly suspect that it does not because of one or both of these:

- It is in a different folder, e.g. a subfolder. The solution is to write out the path (relative or absolute) in the `ExcelList` file.
- It is spelled differently, e.g. with a small `T` or capital postfix (`XLSX`), a spacebar or the like. The solution is of course to make the filenames in the `ExcelList` and the actual filenames match.

Comment: Jonas is almost certainly correct re the first problem: the system is working, in that is extracting a filename ("Trials_20_95.xlsx") from your outer conditions file but simply can't find it. Do you have it in a subdirectory? The second error is because `eval()` isn't the right thing to do here. You have a string representing a filename ("Trials_20_95.xlsx") but using `eval` tries to turn that into a variable name, which doesn't exist (notice that Python has dropped the ".xlsx' portion here: it interprets the .xlsx as an attribute of a variable called "Trials_20_95").

Comment: Thank you very much Jonas. It turns out it was a simple directory problem as you and Michael suggested. I moved the experiment from a different computer, and in the process of setting up directories on the current system, I missed that a subdirectory had been added in the path. Again, thank you for your help. I edited the Excel file to include the subdirectory in its search, and everything is running smoothly now.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please accept it by ticking it off so that others can see that there is a solution. I'm glad you found a solution.